# Can not configure Require.js baseUrl

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have the following application structure:

```
+ project
  + app
  + script
    + vendors
      + backbone
      + underscore
      - require.js
      - require.config.js
  package.json
```

I have installed all dependencies using `jam.js`. The `package.json` is looks like this:

```json
{
   "name": "Project",
   "jam": {
             "packageDir": "app/scripts/vendor",
         "baseUrl": "app",
         "dependencies": {
                 "backbone": null
         }
   }
}
```

The baseUrl is set to the app folder, and if I run my application from 
`localhost/project/app` it's working just fine. But eventually in the back-end my app `index.html` is included in a php web page so all modules urls are broken, for example:

```
GET http://builder1.localhost/user/scripts/vendor/require.js 404 (Not Found)
```

instead of loading:

```
localhost/project/app/scripts/vendor/require.js
```

How can I configure the `'baseUrl'` so it will know that I'm been load via `http://builder1.localhost/user/`?

Answer (score 0):

Your entry script (the first script loaded by require.js) should have something similar to the following

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: "/another/path",
    paths: {
        "some": "some/v1.0"
    },
    waitSeconds: 15
});
require( ["some/module", "my/module", "a.js", "b.js"],
    function(someModule,    myModule) {
        //This function will be called when all the dependencies
        //listed above are loaded. Note that this function could
        //be called before the page is loaded.
        //This callback is optional.
    }
);
```

That is taken straight from there documentation. Double check your code. Base URL is better if its an absolute path and not relative.